# Memory Pool in C for windows application (Not interested in C++)

Tags: c, windows, memory-management, memory-pool

I am trying to understand memory pool concept in C. I understand memory pool is a pre-allocated memory space with a fixed size. But I want know is there any standard Library or API that can help to implement memory pool in C ?

I Don't want to implement memory pool my self in C , I am in search of some **STANDARD API or LIB for my C program that can do memory pool operation**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows API offers that you can create your own heap (block of virtual memory):

[HeapCreate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366599%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Then you use [HeapAlloc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366597%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [HeapFree](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366701%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) within that.